# How to calculate an angle from a rotation matrix

Tags: matrix, rotation

I have a given 3x3 rotation matrix and I want to calculate the rotation angle around z axis. How do I get there?
For example, in this case below, how did they calculated the "-30deg rotation around the x axis"? Or how did they get to the "-74deg" value around that axis?

[image]

This is my original matrix:

[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It is simple if the rotation matrix is just a rotation matrix and there is no scaling. Here  is a site that explains in more pretty terms then I am willing to diagram here. Basically the rotation matrix is composed of sinf(x) and cosf(x) of euler angles (well you can think of it like that at least). You can therefore use values within it to back calculate the euler angles.

http://nghiaho.com/?page_id=846

If you have scaling involved you will need to normalize each row of the matrix first. Then apply the above method.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. However, I don't have matlab to use this code you sent. Is there a way/website that I can input my value and it will give me the angles?

Comment: you don't need matlab, just the math  for the Z axis you need atan2(r21,r11), for your original matrix that is atan2(0,1) look at the decomposing matrix section of that link. It has the equations for all 3 Euler angles.